# Unable to change a record's owner id using API

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trying to update an Account's owner ( the one which is set by using the Assign button ), by using the REST api in Dynamics CRM.
My request looks as followws:

```
uri: [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts(AccountID)
Request type: Patch
Request body: {"ownerid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(UserID)"}
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
message=Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  ---->  InnerException : System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightInputContext.CreateTextReader(Stream messageStream, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightInputContext..ctor(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings)
   at Microsoft.OData.Json.ODataJsonFormat.CreateInputContext(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings)
   at Microsoft.OData.ODataMessageReader.ReadFromInput[T](Func`2 readFunc, ODataPayloadKind[] payloadKinds)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger).
```

Looking into the Dynamics documentation here: [Dynamics Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/account?view=dataverse-latest), I think that the field I should use in the payload, would be ownerid_accounts, but the request still fails.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong in my request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got what I was doing wrong. Using Fiddler, I've seen that my request was, in fact:

```
"{"ownerid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(UserID)"}"
```

so I needed to remove the beginning and end quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the payload is not valid. Try using the following:

```
{"ownerid@odata.bind": "/systemusers(UserID)"}
```

Comment: Sorry. That's how my request looks like, when I get this error. I left the json curly brackets out at the beginning.

Comment: Can you please double-check that UserID is a valid Guid and it doesn't contain curly brackets like { and/or }?

Comment: I've checked and the system user is a valid guid. If I try to get the user's details, by the userID, I manage to do it, so my request seems wrong. I also got an example from someone, and it looks like this: record[ownerid@odata.bind <mailto:ownerid@odata.bind> ] = "/systemusers(userID)";
but with this I get the same error.